# Samsung s22 ultra phone show tablet app on play store(App for only tablet)

Tags: android, tablet, samsung-mobile

But on the play store my app show on Samsung s22 ultra and install successfully how to restrict app on Phone

I have created an Android application that is targeted to tablet devices only. In Android Manifest I have set the following screen support:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manually exclude phones from Google Play Console.

1. Go to,

   ```
   Reach and Devices -> Device Catelog -> Manage Devices -> Exclude Devices
   ```
2. Then add a *Device Type* filter as *Phone*.
3. Select all and Save.

It can take upto a few hours until changes are visible around the globe.